# How to extract a substring matching a pattern from a Unix shell variable

Tags: regex, unix, shell, sed, grep

I'm relatively new to Unix shell scripting. Here's my problem. I've used this script...

```
isql -S$server -D$database -U$userID -P$password << EOF > $test
exec MY_STORED_PROC
go
EOF

echo $test
```

To generate this result...

```
Msg 257, Level 16, State 1:
Server 'MY_SERVER', Procedure 'MY_STORED_PROC':
Implicit conversion from datatype 'VARCHAR' to 'NUMERIC' is not allowed.  Use
the CONVERT function to run this query.
(1 row affected)
(return status = 257)
```

Instead of echoing the isql output, I would like to extract the "257" and stick it in another variable so I can return 257 from the script. I'm thinking some kind of sed or grep command will do this, but I don't really know where to start.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

bash can strip parts from the content of shell variables.

`${parameter#pattern}` returns the value of $parameter without the part at the beginning that matches `pattern`.

`${parameter%pattern}` returns the value of $parameter without the part at the end that matches `pattern`.

I guess there is a better way to do this, but this should work.
So you could combine this into:

```
% strip the part before the value:
test=${test#Msg }
% strip the part after the value:
test=${test%, Level*}
echo $test
```

If you're interested in the `(return status = xxx)` part, it would be:

```
result=${test#*(result status = }
result=${result%)*}
echo $result
```

The relevant section of the bash manpage is "Parameter Expansion".

Answer (score 2):

Here is a quick and dirty hack for you, though you should really start learning this stuff yourself:

```
RC=`tail -1 $test |sed 's/(return status = \([0-9]\+\))/\1/'`
```

Comment: Thanks. That's why I'm asking: I wanted to see experienced Unix coders would solve a real-world problem, so I could learn to do it myself. So in this case, the tail command pipes the last line of $test to the sed command, which returns whatever's inside the \\( and )\ (assuming the overall pattern matches). Is that right?

Comment: Yes, whatever is between the \\( and \\) is then given by \1 in the substitution. [0-9]\+ means match one or more digits.